# Problem displaying MGPanoramaView with Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im trying to display a Google Street View View for iOS and followed the official tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview#maps_ios_streetview_add-swift.

But I am getting following errors, which are not really helping me at all. Probably has to do with GL.

```
2021-06-06 23:25:45.749005+0200 GeoGuesser[73101:2682973] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
W0606 23:25:46.370050       1 IOSGLContext.mm:109] Failed to attach the color renderbuffer to the layer.renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable: failed.
```

Is someone encountering the same problem?

Note:
Displaying a normal Google Map View is no problem, so its not a API Key problem.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this going?